# ADFS 3.0 not passing claims from ADFS 2.0

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0, adfs3.0

I have following parts:
web server 
->
my ADFS 2.0 server
->
client ADFS 2.0 server

Communication goes:
web -> my adfs -> client adfs -> my adfs -> web

everything is working here with my adfs 2.0.
Problem is with my new ADFS 3.0 server which is not passing claims which I get from client (any claim, first name, email, ID, nothing,...)
As I can see on web part **CipherData** is much shorter then when I used to use my ADFS 2.0 server.

Is there any conflict or something else between ADFS 2.0 and 3.0 or I need extra setup?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with federating ADFS 2.0 and 3.0.

Where is your ADFS 3.0 server in this path?

web server -> my ADFS 2.0 server -> client ADFS 2.0 server

Did you configure the federation via the metadata?

Did you add pass-through rules to the "middle" ADFS?

Comment: 1. web server -> my ADFS 3.0 server -> client ADFS 2.0 server / 
2. federation of client I have configured over metadata and my adfs I have configured manually as I did my old adfs 2.0 / 
3. Yes I did as same as on old adfs 2.0

Comment: This is all WS-Fed? So you replaced ADFS 2.0 (which worked) with ADFS 3.0 (which doesn't)? Do you still have the ADFS 2.0 instance? Have you manually compared all the claims rules etc.between 2.0 and 3.0? What did you mean by CipherData? On the RP do you get any error? Do you get any claims on the RP?

Comment: Yes I still have and all claims are same. I used fiddler tto race and as I can see all claims are sent to my adfs 3.0 but not passed to my web. CipherData is encrypted part of token which contains claims

Comment: here is video how I configured: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7vjilbil83lwncm/adfs_setup.mp4?dl=0

Comment: The only problem I can see is the email one. Your claims are being derived from the client IDP so trying to derive any claims from your AD won't work. All claims must be pass-through.

Comment: But they are not, do you have any idea what else could be a problem?

Comment: Make all the claims pass-through for both the CP and the app RP and see what happens.

Comment: how can I pass all claim types?

Comment: I meant pass through all the claims that you require - you need one pas-through rule per claim.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107069/discussion-between-nzpcmad-and-croios).

Comment: Found problem. I should use for example: http://sts.msft.net/user/PrimarySID instead of http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid